# Weird parsing error upon edit of the file

Tags: typescript

I am having an issue I for the life of me cannot understand or fix.

I have an index.ts file, it is used in a constants file. If I change a SINGLE character in this file I get an error saying "Line 0: Parsing error: Cannot read properties of undefined reading ('map')"

BUT, whenever I revert the file back to how it was before I changed a character inside, the project compiles successfully.

I've tried messing with typescript / eslint / parse / resolutions, upgrading, downgrading versions. Nothing changed

I've tried many things that have been said online for that error but seems my issue is unique to when I edit the file.

Comment: Could you provide your code?

Comment: Without a [mre] it's really hard to even imagine how to help here.

Comment: maybe it's about encoding the file